# How to make the bot answer the user, when the bot responded and the user wanted to continue, like a conversation (but without repeating)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

Exemple:

```
user: "Hello!" - bot: "Hi! You wanna help with the codes?"


user: "No" - bot: "Okay!"
```

But but it happens only when user says hello. I don't want him responds "Okay!" when a user say "No" in any sentences... 
 the code then I use to the bot reply the user is:

```
client.on('message', async message => { 
if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("hello")) {
    message.channel.send("Hi! You wanna help with the codes?");
}
});
```

Sorry for my errors of english, I don't speak so much english...

Anyway, someone can help me?

ESPECIAL THANKS: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5896453/naszos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a state for user and decide where to go next based on user's answer, for example(I assumed some kind of id on client object):

```
const userStates = {};

const replies = {
  "": [
    {
      messages: ["hello"],
      answer: "Hi! You wanna help with the codes?",
      next_state: "asked_to_help",
    },
  ],
  asked_to_help: [
    {
      messages: ["no"],
      answer: "Okay :(",
      next_state: "",
    },
    {
      messages: ["yes"],
      answer: "Yay, tell me more!",
      next_state: "some_next_stage",
    },
  ],
};

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  userStates[client.id] = userStates[client.id] || "";
  const text = message.content.toLowerCase();
  const possibleReplies = replies[userStates[client.id]].filter((reply) =>
    reply.messages.includes(text)
  ); // filter by matching messages
  const reply = possibleReplies [Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleReplies .length)]; // get random answer from valid ones
  if (reply) {
    message.channel.send(reply.answer);
    userStates[client.id] = reply.next_state;
  } else {
    message.channel.send("I dont understand :(");
  }
});
```

Comment: hey man, apers this error:  (node:18318) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
What happened?

Comment: Probably something else than string was sent, let me double check my code

Comment: Well, I not modificate your code to test firt... Probably was beacause I don't modificate... Sorry man, I am so bad in Javascipt... What I wanna modificate? 
  :(

Comment: Yeah, a typo, check it now (and keep in mind I used `client.id` which I have no idea if you have access to)

Comment: The one who gets caught up in developer mode?

Comment: (node:20078) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'replies' before initialization"

Comment: I've edited the answer 40 minutes ago, give a try after those fixes :) (replies in function got renamed and I fixed a typo)

Comment: Oh, sorry man, I have not seen it! Thank you so much man! (thank you for the patience! lol)

Comment: Man, I think no work ;-;
"(node:20673) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"

Comment: You also need to initialize userState somewhere, for example on connection `userStates[client.id] = {}` or even from a state from database or something. You can also make it on every call but it's not the best option, let me edit it once more so that it works out of box

Comment: I've added `userStates[client.id] = userStates[client.id] || "";` on the first line of message handler, it should fix the undefined error.

Comment: YEAAH! IT WORK MAN! MAN, I DON'T HAVE WORDS TO THANKS YOU!!! THANKS SO MUUUCH!!!   :D

Comment: Glad I could help :)